# How to to get same replacement rows and data?

Tags: r, azure

I have a model with "enter data manually" on azure with one R module, here is the colomns:

```
Region_ID, Log_Type, CITY_ID, Ad_Slot_Width, Ad_Slot_Floor_Price, Creative_ID, Paying_Price
217,2,3, 335, Na, 5, 255
```

Here is the variables in the R module:

```
test2$Region_ID<- as.numeric(test2$Region_ID)
test2$City_ID<- as.numeric(test2$City_ID)
test2$Ad_Slot_Width<- as.numeric(test2$Ad_Slot_Width)
test2$Ad_Slot_Floor_Price<- as.numeric(as.factor(test2$Ad_Slot_Floor_Price))
test2$Paying_Price<- as.numeric(test2$Paying_Price)
test2$Creative_ID<- as.numeric(test2$Creative_ID)

Here is error when executing it:
Execute R Script Piped (RPackage) : The following error occurred during 
evaluation of R script: R_tryEval: return error: Error in ` 
$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "City_ID", value = numeric(0)) : replacement has 0 
rows, data has 1
```

Where is wrong? How to get the same replacement rows and data?
Thanks,
Ann

Answer (score 0):

You forgot that R is case sensitive. 
This should remove your error.

```
test2$CITY_ID<- as.numeric(test2$CITY_ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Replacement i.e. RHS, vector is empty.

Add a vector to all your replacement vectors while updating the data types.

For eg.: for your case, test2 data expects 1 element each:

```
# insert 0 or NA or whatever you like to hold the place or 
# enter what you desire to enter manually here itself

test2$Region_ID <- as.numeric(0)
```

General Case:

```
test2$Region_ID <- as.numeric(rep(0,nrow(test2))
```